# Delegates and retain cycles?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

Edit: I'm really sorry. I edited the confusing errors I made in my post.

I have these `ivars` declared in `WhereamiViewController.h`:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
IBOutlet UITextField *locationTitleField;
```

The author writes that since `WhereamiViewController` owns `locationManager` and `locationManager's` delegate is the `WhereamiViewController`, `locationManager` delegate must be set to `nil` in the `WhereamiViewController's` `dealloc` method because the delegate is `assigned` instead of `weak`. In the `.xib` file `worldView` and `locationTitleField` are set to delegate the `File's Owner`, but why don't those two delegates need to be set to `nil` when both of them are also `assign` instead of `weak`?

PS: It's using ARC

Comment: This is probably a pre-ARC version of the "big nerd" book, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to set it to `nil` simply as a precautionary measure. Did I Confuse you? Let me explain.

The setting to `nil` has really nothing to do with `retain` `release` cycle, it is simply to avoid `locationManager` sending delegate call to your controller. For instance, if `locationManager` is updating location meanwhile your controller is released, the `locationManager` still having the `delegate` reference set to your view controller, will call the delegate with location parameters.

But since you controller has been deallocated, the call will result in bad memory access.

However, if you set it to `nil`, exception will not be thrown since manipulatin of `nil` pointers has no affect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you say I need to take that precaution for all delegated objects? Such as UITextField and MKMapView?

Comment: well not really. This measure is for those services that run in background like locationManager. As far as `UITextField`s are concerned, they send delegate calls as long as user can interact with them and user can only interact with them as long as they are on the screen and if they are on the screen your ViewController is well and alive =)

Answer (score 2):

> `locationManager must be set to nil in the WhereamiViewController's dealloc method`

The [`CLLocationManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/delegate) does not retain its delegate. Even if it did setting the `locationManager` to `nil` in `dealloc` will do nothing to break a retain cycle because a retain cycle would result in `dealloc` never being called. There needs to be some other event that breaks the retain cycle such as dismissing/popping the view controller.

> but why don't those two need to be set to nil?

If t is documented that the class does not retain the delegate then you do not have to worry about a retain cycle. Sometimes the documentation comes from just looking at the header file and looking for `assign` rather than `strong` or `retain`. `CLLocationManager` does not retain its delegate so you do not have to assign `locationManager` to `nil`. If, however, the `locationManager` may still receive events after your class is deallocated you should set its delegate to `nil` in the `dealloc` method to prevent callbacks after your class is deallocated.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    //Prevent callbacks after dealloc
    //Useful if locationManager is a singleton or used elsewhere
    locationManager.delegate = nil;

    [locationManager release]; //If not ARC
    [super dealloc];//If not ARC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `locationManager` must be set to nil in the WhereamiViewController's dealloc method.

That doesn't do anything.

If you are using manual reference counting, it should be *released* in WhereamiViewController's dealloc (because WhereamiViewController owns it).  If you have a property that wraps the locationManager instance variable, you can set that property to nil in dealloc to achieve the same effect, as long as the property is a retain property.  However, using properties in dealloc is generally discouraged by Apple.

If you re using ARC, the compiler will do all that for you.

What you should be doing in WhereamiViewController's dealloc, is setting the location manager's delegate to nil because, if the location manager survives beyond the dealloc, you do not want it sending delegate messages to the non existent WhereamiViewController.

Again, with ARC if the delegate of CLLocationManager is a weak reference, the nilling is done for you.

> but why don't those two need to be set to nil?

They don't, but the same reasoning applies to their delegates, when their delegates get deallocated.